# a small application for use of graphs on software modelling

Tags: graph, architecture, reverse-engineering, modeling

I am searching use of graphs in software analysis or software modelling.I come up with graph mining topic.Now I need to develop a small application on software quality,modelling,analysis using graph.In my mind there is some ideas on call graphs ,dependency graphs for functions,but i am not sure.Any suggestion to go further on a topic?

Comment: Have you tried IDA? (RE) and of course Visual Studio give a good code analysis

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/ - It's for your research I guess

Answer (score 0):

Why kind of graph you want?

If you want create dependency, uml cass diagram etc graphviz is a good choice.

Comment: i need just idea for choosing topic and implementing an application on it.i don't need a tool.